# Error fatal al llamar la funcion exec

Tags: php

Hola cuando el codigo exactamente y deberia funcionar me da este error y no se porque el error me da en esta parte del codigo:

```
$users->exec($sql);
```

Codigo completo:

```
<?php

require_once 'database.php';

$database_connection = database_connect();

$users = $database_connection->query('SELECT * FROM coffee')->fetchAll();

$title = 'Home';
$content = '
<h4>Title 1</h4>
<form method="POST">
<table>
<tr>
    <td><input type="text" name="fname" required placeholder="First Name"></td>

</tr>
<tr>
    <td><input type="text" name="lname" required placeholder="Last Name"></td>

</tr>
<tr>
     <td><input type="number" name="age" required placeholder="Age" min="10" > </td>

</tr>
<tr>
    <td><input type="submit" name="insert"></input></td>

</tr>
';


$content .=  '</form></table>';
try {
      // set the PDO error mode to exception

    $sql = "INSERT INTO MyGuests (firstname, lastname, email)
    VALUES ('John', 'Doe', 'john@example.com')";
    // use exec() because no results are returned
    $users->exec($sql);
    echo "New record created successfully";
    }
catch(PDOException $e)
    {
    echo $sql . "<br>" . $e->getMessage();
    }

$conn = null;

include 'Template.php';
      ?>
```

Comment: ¿Cuál error te da?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usando [`PDO`](http://php.net/manual/es/book.pdo.php) sucede que:

- Al hacer `$users = $database_connection->query('SELECT * FROM coffee')->fetchAll()`, obtienes un `array`.
- Es decir, `$users` es un `array`.

Solución: usar `$database_connection` en lugar de `$users`.

```
//
$sql = "INSERT INTO MyGuests (firstname, lastname, email)
VALUES ('John', 'Doe', 'john@example.com')";
$database_connection->exec($sql);
```